# How to work with emacs and mysql

Tags: mysql, emacs

I'm getting the message `unable to locate SQL program 'mysql'` when I attempt to enter sql mode in Emacs. However, I'm able to access mysql just fine via terminal.

For the record, I'm using user and password as root, server as localhost and a database of my choosing. I just don't know why this is happening.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs uses the directories listed in the `exec-path` variable to look for programs. You can add to it like so:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin")
```

The following shell command should give you the correct value to use:

```
dirname `which mysql`
```

Comment: @Glassjawed, if using OS X also consider the `exec-path-from-shell` package.