# Setting `sql-mysql-program` in emacs

Tags: mysql, macos, emacs

There are at least three major overviews that come up when searching for information on using sql with emacs (due to my insufficient reputation I can't 'afford' to link to them here).

I can find no mention in any of them of the need to set the variable `sql-mysql-program` when working with *mysql* servers. Yet I could not get `M-x sql-mysql` to work without following the advice from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141159/emacs-and-mysql-on-mac) to set this variable as follows:

`(setq sql-mysql-program "/path/to/your/mysql")`

In fact, the only tutorials/documentation I've seen highlighting this variable are in the above SO question and another SO question about "emacs-how-to-use-ssh-tunnel-to-connect-to-remote-mysql" (which again I can't link to because of insufficient reputation.)

An alternate solution seems to be suggested here [How to work with emacs and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454508/how-to-work-with-emacs-and-mysql)]), which suggests changing the value of the emacs `exec-path`.

The question is, which of these options is preferable, or is it simply a matter of taste?

And what is the significance of the fact that none of the above-linked overviews of sql/emacs mentions the need to get emacs to recognize the binary? Is there something wrong with my emacs?

I spent a long time combing the **sql.el** source to try to understand what was going on and I do see a `(defcustom sql-mysql-program "mysql"…)`but in my case at least that did not seem to do the trick (perhaps because I'm starting emacs up with `-q` option?).

PS. In case it matters, my `M-x emacs-version` is `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0, NS apple-appkit-1187.40) of 2015-05-01`, which I am running on an older Mac (10.8.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this can be *generalised* to a question of:

> What do I do if Emacs can't find an executable?

which is where the `exec-path` list comes into play.

As noted in <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Shell` <kbd>RET</kbd>, the `exec-path` list is initialised from the environment variable `PATH` when Emacs is started (see also `(emacs) General Variables`), so there are multiple ways to populate that list with the values you need.

Using an absolute path to `sql-mysql-program` is also fine, but potentially less portable. It's up to you, really.